# Facebook Locations, Groups etc.

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to extract a list of ALL locations Facebook has stored, together with their Facebook Id. Would it be possible to do the same with for example sports teams? Companies? etc.

Many Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - this is not possible.  Facebook does not make this information publicly accessible.

Comment: So basically Facebook allows you to access places (or other objects) if you have the place's Facebook Id. Many thanks for the clarification.